# Bxslider the preloader runs in an infinite loop when there is no image

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

When I insert an image that does not exist, eg https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11wz.png bxslider is loading infinitely without ever reaching load.

This is my js:

```
$('.lstsl').bxSlider({slideWidth: 120,minSlides: 2,maxSlides: 9,slideMargin: 15,preloadImages:'visible',onSliderLoad: function(){ $(".lstsl").show(); }});
```

And this my html

```
<ul class="lstsl" style="display:none">
    <li><img src="http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/spooky-jumps/_thumb_100x100.png" width="270" height="270"  alt="My title" /><a href="#">My title</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/spooky-jumps/_thumb_100x100b.png" width="270" height="270"  alt="My title" /><a href="#">My title</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any solution for the bxslider load even if an image is not found?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, modify this line: https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/blob/master/jquery.bxslider.js#L275 to `$(this).one('load error', function() {`

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider this a bug in the plugin, that or a missing feature. all you need to do is modify one line so that on error, it will continue rather than just sitting there waiting for a load event that will never happen.

modify this line: https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/blob/master/jquery.bxslider.js#L275 to

```
$(this).one('load error', function() {
```

Comment: can you update this?  I am not really sure what line you want modified // replaced with.  I think the code updated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **bxslider>jquery.bxslider.js**:

Find this line...

```
$(this).one('load', function() {
```

and replace it with

```
$(this).one('load error', function() {
```

so that in the case of an error, the slides/images will load anyway.

This line is generally on **Line 279** (Current Version 1.5.2)

I hope this is a bit clearer for anyone that needs it - (previous answers contain 404 links which are useless now to people with this problem)